# How to filter Deno tests based on filename?

Tags: typescript, deno

How to filter Deno tests based on filename?

For example, I have the following files:

```
number_1_test.ts
number_2_test.ts
string_test.ts
```

I want to run `number*` tests,

I can't use the following command:

```
deno test number*
```

nor:

```
deno test --filter number*
```

What should I do?

Deno test usage:

`deno test [OPTIONS] [files]... [-- <SCRIPT_ARG>...]`

`--filter <filter>: Run tests with this string or pattern in the test name`

Comment: This is not supported in Deno yet, see the issue thread here: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6365. You can filter by test name with `--filter` but not yet by filename

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) capabilities of your shell. Here's an example using `bash`:

```
$ ls
number_1_test.ts  number_2_test.ts  string_test.ts

$ echo $(ls number*)
number_1_test.ts number_2_test.ts

$ deno test $(ls number*)
running 1 test from ./number_1_test.ts
number 1 ... ok (4ms)
running 1 test from ./number_2_test.ts
number 2 ... ok (6ms)

test result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out (45ms)
```

Comment: What if you're on Windows?